# Using RegEx how do I remove the trailing zeros from a decimal number

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm needing to write some regex that takes a number and removes any trailing zeros after a decimal point. The language is Actionscript 3. So I would like to write:

```
var result:String = theStringOfTheNumber.replace( [ the regex ], "" );
```

So for example:

`3.04000` would be `3.04`

`0.456000` would be `0.456` etc

I've spent some time looking at various regex websites and I'm finding this harder to resolve than I initially thought.

Comment: Wouldn't converting the string to a [Number](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flash-Flex-ActionScript/Data-Type/UseNumbertoconvertstringtoafloatnumber.htm) help?

Comment: Hi Duniyadnd. I understand why you say that. Sadly on large floating point calculations ActionScript 3 does odd things to numbers with decimal places. There are certain results where if we converted the result back to a number it would return it in a floating point format.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Regex:

```
^(\d+\.\d*?[1-9])0+$
```

OR

```
(\.\d*?[1-9])0+$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mD7gK4/7)

**Code:**

```
var result:String = theStringOfTheNumber.replace(/(\.\d*?[1-9])0+$/g, "$1" );
```

Comment: don't know whether op's input start with a decimal point. I added this answer also. Oh this would also works.. `^(\d*\.\d*?[1-9])0+$`

Comment: Thanks to all for your replies. The expressions recommended don't seem to work with ActionScript 3. Can any expression written here translate for this AS3 friendly regex parser: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: see it works here http://www.regexr.com/39mbd . If your regex is enclosed within double quotes then you need to escape the backslash one more time like `(\\.\\d*?[1-9])0+$`

Comment: Hi Avinash. Thanks for your update. Your regex is selecting all numbers after the decimal point. Is it possible for you to show me the regex that would select only the trailing zeros after the decimal point, for example 0.456000 becomes 0.456 etc. Many thanks

Comment: yes, replace the matched characters with `$1`, see the substitution at the bottom in the above link. You could stripoff the trailing zero's only through replace function.

Comment: @Wilf it's different for sed.

Comment: I found that this chokes for 1.000000 and leaves it as is. Setting it to `^(\d+\.\d*?[0-9])0+$` does not break any of the other usecases and trims 1.0000000 to 1.0 (you can try in the demo linked above)

Answer (score 10):

What worked best for me was

```
^([\d,]+)$|^([\d,]+)\.0*$|^([\d,]+\.[0-9]*?)0*$
```

For example,

```
s.replace(/^([\d,]+)$|^([\d,]+)\.0*$|^([\d,]+\.[0-9]*?)0*$/, "$1$2$3");
```

This changes

```
1.10000 => 1.1
1.100100 => 1.1001
1.000 => 1
1 >= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex. Yours actually worked best for me in all my cases. But I think there is one minor issue: When replacing e.g. '234.4500' then it will return the zeros again because the number range at the end include the zero (`[0-9]`). I think it should rather be `^([\d,]+)$|^([\d,]+)\.0*$|^([\d,]+\.[1-9]*?)0*$`

Answer (score 6):

What about stripping the trailing zeros before a `\b` [boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) if there's at least one digit after the `.`

```
(\.\d+?)0+\b
```

And replace with what was captured in the first [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
$1
```

See [test at regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/39mba)

Comment: This works for me. Some inputs: `"Latitude":19.4225447900000000,"Longitude":-99.2162050100000000`.

Comment: How could I make this leave 2 zeros if instead of one if it is all zeros?

Comment: @jamesmpw I guess you would change `0+` to `00+`

Answer (score 3):

```
(?=.*?\.)(.*?[1-9])(?!.*?\.)(?=0*$)|^.*$
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xE6aD0/11

Answer (score 2):

Other answers didn't consider numbers without fraction (like `1.000000` ) or used a lookbehind function (sadly, not supported by implementation I'm using). So I modified existing answers.

- **Match** using `^-?\d+(\.\d*[1-9])?` - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OhSKKe/1) (see matches). This will not work with numbers in text (like sentences).
- **Replace**(with `\1` or `$1`) using `(^-?\d+\.\d*[1-9])(0+$)|(\.0+$)` - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/meXhfG/1) (see substitution). This one will work with numbers in text (like sentences) if you remove the `^` and `$`.

Both demos with examples.

**Side note:** Replace the `\.` with decimal separator you use (`,` - no need for slash) if you have to, but I would advise against supporting multiple separator formats within such regex (like `(\.|,)`). Internal formats normally use one specific separator like `.` in `1.135644131` (no need to check for other potential separators), while external tend to use both (one for decimals and one for thousands, like `1.123,541,921`), which would make your regex unreliable.

Update: I added `-?` to both regexes to add support for negative numbers, which is not in demo.

Answer (score 1):

If your regular expressions engine doesn't support "lookaround" feature then you can use this simple approach:

```
fn:replace("12300400", "([^0])0*$", "$1")
```

Result will be: 123004

Answer (score 1):

I know I am kind of late but I think this can be solved in a far more simple way.
Either I miss something or the other repliers overcomplicate it, but I think there is a far more straightforward yet resilient solution RE:

```
([0-9]*[.]?([0-9]*[1-9]|[0]?))[0]*
```

By backreferencing the first group (\1) you can get the number without trailing zeros.

It also works with .XXXXX... and ...XXXXX. type number strings. For example, it will convert .45600 to .456 and 123. to 123. as well.

More importantly, it leaves integer number strings intact (numbers without decimal point). For example, it will convert 12300 to 12300.

Note that if there is a decimal point and there are only zeroes after that it will leave only one trailing zeroes. For example for the 42.0000 you get 42.0.

If you want to eliminate the leading zeroes too then youse this RE (just put a [0]* at the start of the former):

```
[0]*([0-9]*[.]?([0-9]*[1-9]|[0]?))[0]*
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested few answers from the top:

```
^(\d+\.\d*?[1-9])0+$
(\.\d*?[1-9])0+$
(\.\d+?)0+\b
```

All of them not work for case when there are all zeroes after "." like `45.000` or `450.000`

modified version to match that case: `(\.\d*?[1-9]|)\.?0+$`
also need to replace to '$1' like:

```
preg_replace('/(\.\d*?[1-9]|)\.?0+$/', '$1', $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

And read this 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html  it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what the original question is looking for, but anyone who is looking to format money and would only like to remove **two consecutive** trailing zeros, like so:

```
£30.00 => £30
£30.10 => £30.10 (and not £30.1)

30.00€ => 30€
30.10€ => 30.10€
```

Then you should be able to use the following regular expression which will identify two trailing zeros not followed by any other digit or exist at the end of a string.

```
([^\d]00)(?=[^\d]|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's my solution:

`(((?<=(\.|,)\d*?[1-9])0+$)|(\.|,)0+$)`

My regular expression will only match the trailing 0s, making it easy to do a `.replaceAll(..)` type function.

Breaking it down, part one: `((?<=(\.|,)\d*?[1-9])0+$)`

- `(?<=(\.|,)`: A positive look behind. Decimal must contain a `.` or a `,` (commas are used as a decimal point in some countries). But as its a look behind, it is not included in the matched text, but still must be present.
- `\d*?`: Matches any number of digits lazily
- `[1-9]`: Matches a single non-zero character (this will be the last digit before trailing 0s)
- `0+$`: Matches 1 or more `0`s that occur between the last non-zero digit and the line end.

This works great for everything except the case where trailing 0s begin immediately, like in `1.0` or `5.000`. The second part fixes this `(\.|,)0+$`:

- `(\.|,)`: Matches a `.` or a `,` that will be included in matched text.
- `0+$` matches 1 or more `0`s between the decimal point and the line end.

Examples:

- `1.0` becomes `1`
- `5.0000` becomes `5`
- `5.02394900022000` becomes `5.02394900022`

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for my case, so here's another go at this question:

```
/((?:[^\d.]|^)\d*\.\d*?)(0+)(?=(?:[^\d.]|$))/gm
```

Replace this with the first capture group `$1` to trim trailing zeroes after the decimal for all numbers in the target string.

Here's a breakdown of how it works:

- `(?:[^\d.]|^)` => The character right before a number, or lack thereof if it's the beginning of the string.
- `\d*\.` => Everything up to and including the decimal point.
- `\d*?` => This needs to be lazy (`?`) to let the next pattern consume the trailing zeroes:
- `(0+)` => Matches the trailing zeroes.
- `(?=(?:[^\d.]|$))` => The character at the end of a number, or lack thereof if it's the end of the string.

Here's a [demo on Regex101 ➚](https://regex101.com/r/4rWbHz/4)

---

The above regex will not trim the decimal point itself (`1.00 => 1.`), so an additional substitution might be necessary depending on your needs:

```
/(\d)(?:\.)(\D|$)/gm
```

Replace this with `$1$2` to trim the unnecessary decimal points.

Answer (score -1):

Is it really necessary to use regex? Why not just check the last digits in your numbers? I am not familiar with Actionscript 3, but in python I would do something like this:

```
decinums = ['1.100', '0.0','1.1','10']
for d in decinums:
    if d.find('.'):
        while d.endswith('0'):
            d = d[:-1]
    if d.endswith('.'):
        d = d[:-1]
    print(d)
```

The result will be:

```
1.1
0
1.1
10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'1.00020'.replace(/\.0+$|(?<=\.\d*?)0+$/, '')
```

match
0
0.00
1.00
1.001
1.00100

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.